# Flutter Riverpod: Why autodisposable not getting recreated once disposed?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I have an `autodispose` state provider which takes an `id` and returns an `enum` and that `id` is also being provided by another autodisposable state provider.

```
final id = ref.watch(taskBeingEditedProvider(parentID));
final currentPicker = ref.watch(currentPickerProvider(id));

///This is the provider which gives me which picker is open for the given task
final currentPickerProvider = StateProvider.family
.autoDispose<OpenPicker, String>((ref, __) {
  return OpenPicker.none;
});

enum OpenPicker { start, end, none, startTime, endTime }

final taskBeingEditedProvider = StateProvider.autoDispose.family<String?, String>((ref, string) {
   return null;
});
```

Let's say I have `task1` and `task2`. When I change  `taskBeingEditedProvider` to `task2` then `currentPickerProvider` with id `task1` gets disposed which is expected but if I change `taskBeingEditedProvider` back to `task1` then `currentPickerProvider`  is not getting recreated. As a workaround I am using `ref.keepAlive()` inside `currentPickerProvider` but that's not right.